# Link blog with Facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook, share

is there any way to link a blog to Facebook fan page (and vice versa) so that whenever there is a new blog post, it automatically shares to blog's Facebook fan page in the way that every time there is a new like/share/comment on Facebook side, it will propagate to the particular blog post and vice versa? (If you like/share/comment particular post on blog it will propage to Facebook fan page post).

I've stumbled upon solutions like RSS feeding Facebook fan page from blog feed as well as adding like/share buttons to blog posts. But as far as I know, neither of those provide this kind of link between the blog and the fanpage.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create an App, authorize a Page Admin with `publish_actions` and `manage_pages`, request a Page Token and post with the feed endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed#publish

It´s not that simple and too much for one single Stackoverflow thread, but there are answered questions for all those steps. Here are some links about Access Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thank you luschn. It's much more complex that i thought, I think I will stick to standard stuff for now.

Comment: well, it´s not THAT complex, read through my last link (the blog article) and search for "Extended Page Access Token without creating some code". there´s a step by step explanation. the rest is just using the api with the page token - see the first link in my answer for the reference with example code.